# Makefile to build C and CPP files

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have been looking for a Makefile to compile a huge project which contains lots of C and C++ files. I have used Eclipse to compile it successfully but I want to go to a standalone Makefile.
I found this generic Makefile that works really well with my project except it can only compile C or C++ files but not both in one run...so it fails at Linking time.

The bits of original Makefile that compile for CPP or C:

```
        SRC_EXT = cpp
        OURCES = $(shell find $(SRC_PATH)/ -name '*.$(SRC_EXT)' -printf '%T@\t%p\n' \
        SOURCES = $(shell find $(SRC_PATH)/ -name '*.$(CPP_EXT)' -o -name '*.$(C_EXT)' -printf '%T@\t%p\n' \
                            | sort -k 1nr | cut -f2-)
        # fallback in case the above fails
        rwildcard = $(foreach d, $(wildcard $1*), $(call rwildcard,$d/,$2) \
                                $(filter $(subst *,%,$2), $d))
        ifeq ($(SOURCES),)
            SOURCES := $(call rwildcard, $(SRC_PATH)/, *.$(SRC_EXT))
        endif
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:$(SRC_PATH)/%.$(SRC_EXT)=$(BUILD_PATH)/%.o)
DEPS = $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)
```

I tried to modify it to be:

```
SRC_EXT = cpp c
SOURCES = $(shell find $(SRC_PATH)/ -name '*.$(CPP_EXT)' -o -name '*.$(C_EXT)' -printf '%T@\t%p\n' \
                    | sort -k 1nr | cut -f2-)
# fallback in case the above fails
rwildcard = $(foreach d, $(wildcard $1*), $(call rwildcard,$d/,$2) \
                        $(filter $(subst *,%,$2), $d))
ifeq ($(SOURCES),)
    SOURCES := $(call rwildcard, $(SRC_PATH)/, *.$(SRC_EXT))
endif
```

But i'm not sure what to do with the OBJECTS directive to make it work with the multiple extensions:

```
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:$(SRC_PATH)/%.$(SRC_EXT)=$(BUILD_PATH)/%.o)
```

Can anybody help with this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, replace `.cpp` by `.o`, then replace the remaining `.c` by `.o`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure what you mean by that. Do you mean I should compile the CPP files first then C files? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: No, I mean in the line where the OBJECTS variable is assigned in the Makefile, a text replacement on the filenames happens - suffix SRC_EXT is replaced by suffix ".o". You need to replace both suffixes by ".o".

Comment: I see. Any suggestions as to how I should do that? using && won't do the trick and it is almost my first complex Makefile I'm writing. How can I combine them?

Comment: You could use the patsubst function, which you can nest. Or you can continue to use substitution references, with a temporary variable.

Comment: But, after a second thought, you could just ignore my advice and just replace ANY suffix by .o. The basename and addsuffix functions could be useful for that.